# i want to make a video player page

Tags: codeigniter, video

I've managed to post the video to the database and the video is already showing in the asset/img_galeri directory, but when I open the video player page, it can't be played.

//My controller :

```
function tambah_gallery(){
        cek_session_akses('gallery',$this->session->id_session);
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $config['upload_path'] = 'asset/img_galeri/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp4';
            $config['max_size'] = '500000'; // kb
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload('d');
            $hasil=$this->upload->data();
            if ($hasil['file_name']==''){
                $data = array('id_album'=>$this->input->post('a'),
                            'username'=>$this->session->username,
                            'jdl_gallery'=>$this->input->post('b'),
                            'gallery_seo'=>seo_title($this->input->post('b')),
                            'keterangan'=>$this->input->post('c'));
            }else{
                $data = array('id_album'=>$this->input->post('a'),
                            'username'=>$this->session->username,
                            'jdl_gallery'=>$this->input->post('b'),
                            'gallery_seo'=>seo_title($this->input->post('b')),
                            'keterangan'=>$this->input->post('c'),
                            'gbr_gallery'=>$hasil['file_name']);
            }
            $this->model_app->insert('gallery',$data);  
            redirect($this->uri->segment(1).'/gallery');
        }else{
            $data['record'] = $this->model_app->view_ordering('album','id_album','DESC');
            $this->template->load('administrator/template','administrator/mod_gallery/view_gallery_tambah',$data);
        }
    }
```

//My View :

```
        <div class="blog-detail card shadow mb-4">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-text">
                    <?php echo "$rows[keterangan]"; ?>
                </div>           
                    <?php               
                    $no = 1+$this->uri->segment(4); 
                    foreach ($detailalbum->result_array() as $h) {  
                        if (trim($h['gbr_gallery'])==''){ 
                            $gbr_gallery = 'no-image.jpg'; 
                        } else { 
                            $gbr_gallery = $h['gbr_gallery']; 
                        }
                        ?>
             
                            <h3 class="card-title">
                                <?php echo $no." ".$h['jdl_gallery'];?>
                            </h3>       
                        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                          <source src="<?php echo base_url()."asset/img_galeri/".$gbr_gallery;?>" type="' . $video_type . '">
                          </video>       
                            <div class="card-text">
                                <?php echo $h['keterangan']; ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                            $no++;
                        }
                    ?>
```

I hope the video can be played without automatically downloading

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.